# How can I change the legend size of qqnorm and pairs plot for LME models

Tags: r, lme4, nlme

How can I change the size of the labels and the axis in a qqnorm from a LME model?

I am using qqnorm and pairs to evaluate the assumptions of LME models, using lme4 or nlme.

However, I am not being able to change the axis and legend size using cex function.

Code:

```
qqnorm(model, ~ranef(.) )

pairs(model, ~ ranef(.) | Group) # This is used to check homoscedasticity
```

Comment: the plots are done in `lattice`, so have a wee search on how to change axis labels in for example xyplots. ie `pairs(model, ~ranef(.), scales=list(cex=3))` . ps it would be great if you added an example model / data to your question to allow your code to run

Comment: Aosmith

Thank you. that worked.

How can I change the labels (legends) of the axis size?